# Locking in C# using Environment.TickCount

Tags: c#, locking

I'm porting over some legacy code and noticed that some classes have the following lock object:

```
protected readonly object _stateLock = Environment.TickCount;
```

is there any advantage to this over new object()?
Another lock object I see passed around is

```
private Nullable<int> _sLock = new Nullable<int>(Environment.TickCount);
```

Any advantage to using this?

Comment: I can't imagine any advantages to locking on a boxed int. Whoever wrote that was probably just overlooking the simplest method of creating a lock object, a simple `new object()`.

Comment: The only advantage of the second snippet is that you'll never ever get a deadlock.  The *lock* statement must box it and that always generates a unique object.  You never get a working lock either of course.  This programmer had no clue what he was doing.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no advantage whatsoever. Both `Environment.TickCount` and a `Nullable<int>` value are value types and will be boxed, i.e. wrapped in a new `object` reference.

The second version of your code is actually way worse. The first, where `TickCount` is used, is just an inefficient way to allocate a new `object` reference. But the reference never changes and the lock will otherwise work correctly. The `lock` statement (or rather, the underlying `Monitor` class) doesn't care at all what value is inside the object; all it cares about is the reference itself. So boxing `TickCount`, or `17` or just creating a new `object`, it's all the same.

The second version, where `Nullable<int>` is used is just plain wrong, and will achieve no locking behavior at all. Because `Nullable<int>` is itself a value type, when any code tries to lock on that value, i.e `lock (_sLock)`, the value will be boxed at that point in time, creating a brand new `object` reference just for that lock. Locks only work when each critical section of code that needs to share data also uses the same `object` reference for locking. Since they are all going to get their own new `object` reference, no synchronization will occur at all.

I should also point that the compiler will not normally allow you to do the second version. I.e. if you tried to compile this code, it would fail with an error:

```
Nullable<int> _sLock;

lock (_sLock) { }
```

The error would read

> error CS0185: 'int?' is not a reference type as required by the lock statement

If you actually have code somewhere written as you say, then the person who wrote it bypassed this very useful compiler error by casting the `_sLock` value, e.g. something like:

```
lock ((object)_sLock) { }
```

If I saw code like that, I would immediately question the competency of the person who wrote it, and would insist on reviewing any code they touched that's supposed to be thread-safe, to see what else they screwed up.